# importing in Java from a different directory inside a directory

Tags: java

I have a directory `pj`, which holds two directories, `dirA` and `Tests`. `Tests` has a file, `Test.java` (pj/Tests/Test.java), that imports from `File.java` (pj/dirA/File.java) in `dirA`. How do I specify such an import? I tried `import dirA.*` inside `Test.java` but that failed. `dirA` is a package.

`pj` and `Tests` are not packages (though I can make them be if necessary).

In File.java, the statement is as follows:

```
package dirA;
import list.*;
```

In Test.java, the statements before the class header are as follows

```
import pj.dirA.File;
```

When I do

```
javac Test.java
```

from inside `Tests`, it fails.

Comment: Please mention what is the package path declared in File.java?  if you mention package pj.dirA.File.java then u need to declare in dirA imports pj.* or pj.dirA.File

Comment: import pj.dirA.File; inside Test.java

Comment: Nobody knows how to import a file from another directory to a file inside another directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your File.java:

```
package pj.dirA;
```

and this in your Test.java:

```
package pj.Tests;

import pj.dirA.File;
```

then do javac from the folder which *contains* your pj folder.

Note: I've explained how you can change your current setup to work. Package names that correspond to directories should really be all lowercase.

In java, you don't import directories from anywhere, you can only import packages. This is different if you compare it to C/C++, for instance.

Comment: So Tests has to be a package? That is, in another to import from another directory to a file inside a directory, the file being imported to must be inside a directory?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton in java, things are not imported *inside* any files. This is different from C/C++. You can only use import statements to declare that you want to use some package namespace. In practice, package namespaces also correspond to directories, which might be confusing.

Comment: And yes, packages should be used. It is also *possible* to specify classes in the root package that has no package name, but this is not recommended and it has several drawbacks.